# Where can I find the source code of terminal commands like grep?

Tags: bash, terminal

since I'm new to programming, I wanted to ask where I can find the source code for terminal commands and seeing them with editors like vim. If I type "which grep" for instance and then try "vim /usr/bin/grep", the output is in an unreadable format.

Thanks

Comment: The GNU Grep can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/).

Comment: Can't I see the code directly with the terminal?

Comment: It is a compiled `C` program...

Comment: `grep` is compiled, so if you don't get its source, you can't. Once you get it, you definitely can view it in any tool you like, terminal or not.

Comment: @kallikles The program installed on your computer is a compiled version -- that is, it's been translated from human-readable source code into machine code that the CPU understands (and humans don't, except for *serious* nerds). Once it's in that form, the source code isn't needed, so it usually isn't kept on your computer. Often, the source is never even on your computer to begin with; someone compiled it, and made the machine-code binary available, and that's all that ever got downloaded/installed on your computer.

Comment: Great answer @GordonDavisson! If I program, let's say in python, is it common to jump directly into the source code? Because there, I recognized many IDE's having the ability to jump to the human-readable format directly, which is why I'm wondering why for built-in commands for bash scripts it's not common.

Comment: Python is an interpreted language, not a compiled language (well... it's actually a bit more complicated than that), meaning that it's never fully converted into a just-machine-readable format. You still have the source code right there, so you can see what's going on at that level. An IDE for a compiled language can do similar things **if** it has access to the source code. Without access to the source code, a debugger can still let you see what's happening, but it'll describe it in terms of CPU instructions (assembly language), not source code.

Comment: Also, a lot of developers don't want to give you their source code, because you'd be able to make your own modifications, port it to other platforms, etc. Basically, they'd lose some control over the program. The Open Source movement is a counter to this, trying to make source code more available, so people *can* modify, port, etc programs.

Comment: "Can't I see the code directly with the terminal?", yeas, you can, try: `curl -s https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/grep-3.6.tar.xz | xzcat`

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two different categories of executable on a standard Linux system; compiled and interpreted executables.

grep would be an example of a compiled executable, in that once it's compiled, it's not really human readable any more. There are tools such as disassemblers, that can convert executables up to assembly language, but it's unlikely that the content of the grep command that came with your operating system would have enough information left to recreate readable source from it. If you do open it with vim, on a typical Linux distro, you should see 'ELF' near the start; this shows that it's a binary in the ELF (Executable and Linkable Format) format, which is a format for binary machine-language executables.

The other type of executable is an interpreted executable. This is the kind of file that you can examine with your text editor. A typical approach is to run file on some of the files in /usr/bin ( or indeed any other directory with executables ).

Try this to find a list of files that you might be able to examine. On my ubuntu machine for example file outputs "POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable" for shell scripts.

```
cd /usr/bin
file * | grep -v ELF
```

or if this fails with a `arg list too long` error (thanks @Jetchisel) try the following:

```
cd /usr/bin
find . -type f | xargs file
```

See the comments to your question about getting the source code for grep.

Comment: Until you hit `ARGMAX` , then you will see `arg list too long` or something along the lines

Comment: Good point @Jetschisel; I did this on a fairly small system, with less than 1000 files in /usr/bin. I'll update my answer to account for potentially larger numbers of files there that would trigger this error.